# Selenium deprecated org.open.selenium.internal.Locatable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am starting a project by using a library that depends on the said interface. The library worked well with Selenium 3.14.0. The moment I decided to upgrade Selenium, this deprecation has caused a glitch. I would like to take up this opportunity to contribute back to the library by helping the developer to upgrade his library.
For this, I would like to know what are the alternative mechanisms available nowadays for internal.Locatable.
Note: the Selenium version available as on date of this post is 3.141.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium offers the [org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Locatable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Locatable.html) interface now.